# By default lighthouse giving the performance score for mobile , How to get it for desktop ? Programatically using node module

Tags: lighthouse

What parameter need to be added in the below code to get the performance score for Desktop ?

```
const fs = require('fs');
    const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
    const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
    const log = require('lighthouse-logger');
    
    
    (async () => {
        log.setLevel('info');
        const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({ chromeFlags: ['--headless'] });
        const options = { output: 'json', onlyCategories: ['performance'], port: chrome.port };
        const runnerResult = await lighthouse('url', options);
    
        // `.report` is the HTML report as a string
        const reportJson = runnerResult.report;
        fs.writeFileSync('lhreport.json', reportJson);
    
        // `.lhr` is the Lighthouse Result as a JS object
        console.log('Report is done for', runnerResult.lhr.finalUrl);
        console.log('Performance score was', runnerResult.lhr.categories.performance.score * 100);
    
        await chrome.kill();
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property in the options object:

```
emulatedFormFactor: "desktop"
```

```js
const options = { output: 'json', emulatedFormFactor:"desktop", vonlyCategories: ['performance'], port: chrome.port };
```

Comment: `emulatedFormFactor` is deprecated now. Need to set `preset='desktop'` as of now: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/emulation.md